# Converting from string to integer to solve the ( ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' ) error message in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I've a python code that has different functions, and the code has different functions and main function.
The main function is as follows:

```py
    def main():
        while True:
            ch = menu(['Soil Analysis and Yield Prediction','Supervised Learning','Unsupervised Learning','Exit'])
            print('\n\n')
            if ch==3:
                break
            elif ch==1:
                Sup()
            elif ch==2:
                Usup()
            else:
                stdout.write('\nINVALID RESPONSE, TRY AGAIN .........\n\n')
            #print('{:^204s}'.format('*'*204))
        print('\n\n')
        print('{:^204s}'.format('Authors:\tKshitij Jaiswal, Vibhav , Gaurav Khattar\n'))
        print('{:^204s}'.format('THANKS YOU FOR USING OUR SOFTWARE'))
    
    if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```

When the user enters 1, then certain functions will be called, and if the user enters 2, then other functions will be called.

When I'm running the program, I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-6292cf16da20> in <module>
     17 
     18 if __name__=='__main__':
---> 19     main()
     20 

<ipython-input-11-6292cf16da20> in main()
      1 def main():
      2     while True:
----> 3         ch = menu(['Soil Analysis and Yield Prediction','Supervised Learning','Unsupervised Learning','Exit'])
      4         print('\n\n')
      5         if ch==3:

<ipython-input-10-2a274c21fe19> in menu(x)
      6         print(str(i)+'.',x[i])
      7     stdout.write('\n\nEnter your Choice:\t')
----> 8     return int(stdin.readline())

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

And the function menu() is the as follows:

```
def menu(x):
    print('*'*204)
    print('{:^204s}'.format(x[0]))
    print('\n\n')
    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        print(str(i)+'.',x[i])
    stdout.write('\n\nEnter your Choice:\t')
    return int(stdin.readline())
```

I tried to return int(float(stdin.readline()) but it didn't work. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what did you enter while the code asked for the choice?\

Comment: I coudn`t enter anything coz it gave me the error instantly after writing Prediction                                                                                     



1. Supervised Learning
2. Unsupervised Learning
3. Exit


Enter your Choice:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use stdout and stdin in order to achieve what you want, you can use `input` instead the both of them:

```
def menu(x):
    print('*'*204)
    print('{:^204s}'.format(x[0]))
    print('\n\n')
    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        print(str(i)+'.',x[i])
    return int(input('\n\nEnter your Choice:\t'))
```

It's possible that if you're running your code via some sort of IDE or even Jupyter, the program sends signals to your app, which affects your input.

This is what happened when I put the following loop in my Jupyter notebook (till I stopped it):

```
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    print(stdin.readline())
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

11

12

13

14

15

16

17

18

19

20

21

22

23

24

25
...
```

Also check this article to get a better understanding on the difference between input and stdin

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-input-and-sys-stdin-readline/

Comment: Glad to help!, would appreciate if you select it as the accepted answer